# CRC error on a file splitted by WinRar

Tags: winrar

I have a winrar archive with archive with part 1 and part 2. I have copied them into a same  directory. Now, when I am extracting it, all the files get extracted except one whose some parts are included in both archive and I get CRC error. How can I extract this file?

Answer (score 2):

You can't extract this file due to the CRC error. It means a part of your archive is corrupted or incomplete.

You'll have to copy / download the file again and retry to extract it.

CRC : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check

Comment: I copied it from a DVD. I again copied it but it didn't helped

Comment: So the files are corrupted on the DVD. Maybe the burning of the dvd has crashed.

Comment: How could it possible? I copy/paste the RAR files from DVD and I get no error. I am able to extract all files except one that is common in both parts

Comment: If your copy makes no error, the problem is the burning of the dvd.